# Link a C++ library: Restbed

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, restbed

I just downloaded the restbed library: https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed. I have trouble using it.. In fact, I don't know where to put this library.. (I have Linux Mint 17.2)..

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something using because when I use `#include <restbed>`, the make command says that it cannot find the file..

So, can you tell me where I should put this library on my computer and how I can access it??

Thanks a lot

Comment: How did you configure and install the library?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes, include, sorry.. I change this..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't really configured it.. I just followed their instruction using the basic cmake .. (I don't want any of their other features)

Comment: By default the Compiler will lookup header files in `/usr/include` and libraries in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem or do you still require assistance?

Comment: I have resolved my problem.. Thanks..

I opened an issue on Github, here: https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/issues/35

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details on how this [issue](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/issues/35) was resolved can be found on the projects issue tracker.